# Узнать количество пользователей Facebook приложения

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Можно ли с помощью `API Facebook` как-то узнать количество пользователей приложения, которые играют в него.

Ну или еще как то оценить размер (крупность) приложения Facebook в автоматическом режиме.

Answer (score 1):

У Facebook в Graph API есть [Object Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights) для этого.

Для работы с ней нужен токен с read_insights, поэтому, к сожалению, проилюстрировать примерами прямо здесь не получится.